# Algebraic structures with one binary operation

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need your help.I am studying about algebraic structures.I have a question that I can't solve ..

Let $G=\langle A,*\rangle$ be a monoid with the identity $e$. Let $a\in A$.

İs it possible that $a$ has two different left-inverses, $L_1$ and $L_2$?

Thank you very much for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** For an example of such a thing consider the monoid of set maps $\mathbb{N \to N}$ with composition as the operation.  A function has a left-inverse if and only if it's injective, so pick an injective map (for example $x \mapsto 2x$) and try and find two different left-inverses.

Comment: thanks Jim for help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it certainly is possible.  For example, if $X$ is any set, the set of functions $A=\{f:X\to X\}$ form a monoid under composition.  If $f\in A$ is injective but not surjective, then $f$ *always* has more than one left inverse.  This is because a left inverse $g$ can do anything it wants with the elements that are not in the image of $f$.

In particular, let $X$ be the integers, $X=\mathbb Z$, and consider the function $f:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z$ that is multiplication by 2.  Two natural choices for a left inverse of $f$ are "divide by two and then round down" or "divide by two and then round towards 0."  These will behave differently on negative numbers, but they are both left inverses of $f$.

Comment: thank you very much SMoore